# Handling mixed string with double quotations and numbers to save in csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have three lines that I need to save as header of my csv files. They should look like this:

```
title = "dataset test"
variables = "X", "Y", "Z", "V"
zone t = "Data Field", i = 134, j = 293, k = 5, f=point
```

I am using the following code to create the pandas dataframe:

```
info = pd.DataFrame(['title = "dataset test"',
                    'variables = "X", "Y", "Z", "V"',
                    'zone t = "Data Field", i = 134, j = 293, k = 5, f=point'])
```

And using the following code to write the csv file:

```
with open(fpath, 'w') as myfile:
        info.to_csv(myfile, header=None, index=False)
```

However the output in the csv file is as:

```
"title = ""dataset test"""
"variables = ""X"", ""Y"", ""Z"", ""V"""
"zone t = ""Data Field"", i = 134, j = 293, k = 5, f=point"
```

Below this header there are three columns of number which will be add afterward; the final output should be like this:

```
title = "dataset test"
variables = "X", "Y", "Z", "V"
zone t = "Data Field", i = 134, j = 293, k = 5, f=point
6.1961335E+06   2.3218804E+06   1.3564390E+03
6.1961547E+06   2.3218672E+06   1.3473630E+03
6.1961759E+06   2.3218540E+06   1.3382290E+03
6.1961972E+06   2.3218408E+06   1.3322720E+03
```

which I do it using `df.to_csv(myfile, header=None, index=False, sep='\t',float_format='%.7E')`

Comment: What do the other rows look like? Your headers are being quoted because they contain the quotechar (which is `"` by default). Depending on what you know about the data you're writing, you may be able to adjust the CSV format.

Comment: @hoyland I edited the post to include the rest of the file.

Comment: I think picking a different quote character is all you need--try passing `quotechar="'"`. Everything else is numeric, so it should be safe enough.

Comment: @hoyland using `quotechar="'"` only fixes the problem for the first line. The rest remains the same. I tried to do it line by line but still this only works for the first line.

Comment: Whoops. I totally misread and thought those were your column names. You could do away with the `info` dataframe and just write those three strings to the file. But I'm going to play around and see if I can get `to_csv` to work. (Edit: Not that them being the column names would help--the issue in the later lines was the commas)

Comment: `info.to_csv("test.csv",quotechar="'",  sep='\t', index=False, header=None)` appears give the desired result (if I read properly this time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `\` escape character on this line

```
'variables = "X", "Y", "Z", "V"'
```

Like this

```
'variables = \"X\", \"Y\", \"Z\", \"V\"'
```

Comment: This almost solved the problem. The commas need to be in qoutaion mark. ''variables = \"X\"',' \"Y\"',' \"Z\"',' \"V\"''